# Github/Laravel: Github ignoring /vendor/symfony

Tags: git, symfony, laravel, github

Github keeps ignoring the /vendors/symfony completely.. My .gitignore file contains /vendors, but it still includes the /vendors-folder, so I removed it, and it keeps ignoring my /vendors/symfony folder, and that causes some trouble obviously....

Have any of you any suggestions for this?

Comment: Why do you want to include your vendors folder? You are supposed to ignore it

Answer (score 1):

Vendor folders should be ignored. All dependencies should be put in `composer.json` file and when you get this project from Github to create a new installation, just run `composer install` and your vendor folder will be created and populated with all packages that are present in `require` section of `composer.json` file.

Comment: IT WORKED! BUt now I simply get another error about FileBag redeclaration? https://www.dropbox.com/s/sg8msx70c2gx798/Sk%C3%A6rmbillede%202015-02-09%20kl.%2016.31.04.png?dl=0

Comment: @Sebastian Looks like class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag is declared in two different places. Check your dependencies. Also check if (I don't know how) some modules are not installled twice. Or maybe you redeclare this class in your custom code?